# How to clear all charts from viewer pane in RSTUDIO

Tags: r, rstudio

I have the following code which generates 5 plots in Rstudio Viewer Pane

```
library(highcharter)
library(tidyverse)

for(i in 1:5){

  highchart() %>% 
    hc_add_series(mpg, "point", hcaes(x = displ, y = cty)) %>%
    print()

}
```

How can i delete them with code instead on doing it manually?
searching the forum i tried the following:

```
graphics.off()
dev.off()
while (dev.cur()>1) dev.off()
if(!is.null(dev.list())) dev.off()
```

But none of the above helps me get rid of the plots
i use Rstudio 1.1.423 and R 3.4.3

Thanks
Rafael

Comment: [Note, that I have filed an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/13321).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Viewer Pane in RStudio is different from the Plots Pane. `graphics.off()` will close all of your open graphics devices, but won't do anything to the Viewer Pane, as you demonstrated. `dev.` functions also relate to graphics devices.

I'm not sure if there is a function that will clear your viewer pane, but you can click the little broom icon in RStudio and that will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks i must admit i didn't pay attention to the broom function i wonder if it was in previous versions of RStudio. Anyway for my current purpose the broom function is enough

Comment: Is there a way to do this with a function call instead of by pressing "Clear all viewer items"?

Comment: it would be very useful if there would be a command to do this instead of manually clicking

Comment: [Note, that I have filed an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/13321).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a programatic way to clear the viewer/plot pane with a function:

```r
clear_viewer_pane <- function() {
  dir <- tempfile()
  dir.create(dir)
  TextFile <- file.path(dir, "blank.html")
  writeLines("", con = TextFile)
  rstudioapi::viewer(TextFile) 
}

clear_viewer_pane()
```

Comment: This is very neat.

Comment: Using `file.path(dir, "about:blank")` looks better for me. However, both actually just add a new item to the pane and won't clear it like how we can do with the brush. (BTW nice la linea avatar!)