# Code equivalent to 'broom' icon in viewer pane of RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio

To clear the viewer pane in RStudio, we can click on the 'broom' icon.

Is there a way to do this using R code?

Update: here's an example of how to render something random in the viewer pane (my question is how can we clear the viewer pane using code?)

```
sometext <- "<p>This text will render in the viewer pane</p>"

dir <- tempfile()
dir.create(dir)
TextFile <- file.path(dir, "TextFile.html")

writeLines(sometext, con = TextFile)
rstudioapi::viewer(TextFile)
```

Comment: @duckmayr I will include a screen grab (and perhaps an example) in the question. The viewer pane is different to the global environment (I'm not looking to remove any variables). I'll update the question shortly

Comment: Oh, I think I know what you mean now. Sorry, just os used to people asking the other question

Comment: I don't think this exists, but hope someone can come along and prove me wrong!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clear all charts from viewer pane in RSTUDIO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49217915/how-to-clear-all-charts-from-viewer-pane-in-rstudio)

Comment: It is a good question, but seems to be a duplicate which unfortunately has a negative answer.

Comment: @JohnColeman Thanks John I will check now. Note the viewer pane and the plots pane are also different. I think 'viewer' is a very generic word so it's confusing

Comment: @JohnColeman the related question is indeed about the viewer pane. Looks like it's not possible?

Comment: My guess is that it *should* be possible, if we can work out where the tempfiles being rendered in the viewer are located and delete them?

Comment: I don't really know. [This recent blog post](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/202133558-Extending-RStudio-with-the-Viewer-Pane) is the most detailed description I've found for the Viewer pane but doesn't address the question. If a positive answer is found, it probably lurks somewhere in Shiny. Perhaps you could render something blank to emulate clearing it?

Comment: @JohnColeman I will use your render blank suggestion, as it has the same effect for what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone wondering, this works:

```r
clear_viewer_pane <- function() {
  dir <- tempfile()
  dir.create(dir)
  TextFile <- file.path(dir, "blank.html")
  writeLines("", con = TextFile)
  rstudioapi::viewer(TextFile) 
}

clear_viewer_pane()
```